# execute query until push items to array - React Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-query

I'm trying to execute a query when an array gets to be updated, but the query executes immediately!

So I have `checkedProducts` array I push some data into it when the screen mount, so my goal is to execute the query when this array has data.

here's the hook

```
import {useQuery} from 'react-query';
import {checkAvailableProducts} from '../Api';

export type checkProductItem = {
  product_id: number;
  detail_id: number;
};
export interface checkProducts {
  products: checkProductItem[];
}

export const useCheckAvailableProducts = (products?: checkProducts) => {
  console.log('products-RQ', products);
  return useQuery(
    ['checkAvailableProducts'],
    () => checkAvailableProducts(products),
    {
      enabled: !!products?.products, // OR products?.products.length > 0 not works
    },
  );
};
```

component

```
....
  const [checkedProducts, setCheckedProducts] = useState<checkProducts>();
  const {data: unavailableProducts, refetch} = useCheckAvailableProducts(
    checkedProducts,
  );


  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (cartProducts.length) {
      let productsIDs = cartProducts.map(prod => {
        return {
          product_id: prod.id,
          detail_id: prod.detail_id,
        };
      });
      Promise.all(productsIDs).then(allProductsIDs => {
        console.log('allProductsIDs', allProductsIDs);
        return setCheckedProducts({
          products: allProductsIDs,
        });
      });
    }
  }, [cartProducts]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      refetch();
      console.log('unavailableProducts:', unavailableProducts);
      if (unavailableProducts && unavailableProducts.length > 0) {
        console.log('hey if0update!!!');
        updateCart(unavailableProducts);
      }
    });
    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation, refetch, unavailableProducts, updateCart]);
```

Comment: What is `cardProducts`. A promise?

Comment: @testing_22 it's an array, i used `zustand` so i saved the cart there just get them like this `const cartProducts = useCartProduct(state => state.cartProducts);`

Comment: May I ask you why you `Promise.all` them? Just trying to understand your problem

Comment: @testing_22 I just wait for the `map(..)` to complete iteration then use `Promise.all` to set the state with the resolved data `allProductsIDs`, if I'm wrong correct me ;)

Comment: Well. Not sure. I mean, if the array is made of Promises, so it makes sense using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method

Comment: @testing_22 the issue is in the listener callback, I `refetch()` the query, so maybe they ignore the  `enabled` properly, So I just excuse the `refetch()` if the `checkedProducts?.products.length! > 0` and it works well 